# Dynamic SQL not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure createtables
  Authid current_user as
begin
  execute immediate 'create table newcustomer as select * from customer';
end;

create or replace procedure e
is
begin
 createtables;
 select * from newcustomer; 
end;
```

I got two procedures above. first one will create a new tables called newcustomer, second procedure will call the first procedure and query to the newcustomer table. when I try to compile this code, it says the table is not yet created, I don't really get it as I have called createtables procedure so I assume I have created the table.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why are you creating the table in a procedure? Why not create the table once, then do an ordinary `INSERT AS SELECT`? Or, if the table is only holding temporary data for a session, consider using a Global Temporary Table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Compiling** the second procedure without **executing** the first procedure first will fail, since the table has not been created.

You cannot compile a procedure that relies on objects that do not exist.

Use `EXEC createtables` before creating procedure `e`, and do not call `createtables` in there.

---

Procedure `e` will also not compile because you are not using the results of `select * from newcustomer` as cursor or store the results into variables.

---

**EDIT**:

Instead of procedures, you could use an anonymous block. Put the following into a file and execute it (via SQL*Plus for example):

```
Create Table newcustomer As Select * From customer;

Begin
  Null; --# Do something with your new table in here.
End;
/
```

Comment: thanks for the response but is it possible to have exec createtables inside a procedure as I want all the procedures I have be executed through one entry point which is like my main procedure

Comment: yeah, I got I know the second one would not compile, it is only for demonstration.

Comment: The problem is not the execution of `createTables`, the problem is that your procedure `e` does not compile because it relies on a table that does not yet exist. What should that procedure do? Why can't you just query `customer` instead?

Comment: the e (main procedure) will be my entry point so when I execute this procedure , it should create a new table for me and then I will do a number of data manupulation in this procedure such as insert or delete. to ensure the procedure does not grow too large, I put the create table into new procedure which will be called by the main procedure. I think I really messed up the idea of procedure in pl/sql and other programming language. I am new to pl/sql

Comment: @christine33990: Please check if my updated answer helps you.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, I guess putting code in the file will do, if there is no way to put the 'execute createTables' inside another procedure , i probably just create it beforehand (not inside the procedure), thanks

Comment: The problem is not, that you put them into another procedure. It will also not work when you put the dynamic SQL into your procedure, since Oracle will check for all dependencies when **creating** a procedure. You refer to a table that does not exist, so creation fails.